# Why swift closures are non-escaping by default?

Tags: swift

I found that the swift closure by default is non escaping closure but didn't found any explanation for why this.

Can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 2):

Escaping closures introduce extra memory management concerns. You could create retain loops. `map` (which takes a non-escaping closure) has no concerns about retain loops, so you don't have to add `self` in the closure to remind the caller of the danger. `DispatchQueue.async` takes an escaping closure, and so the caller needs to be a little more thoughtful about the lifetime of the closure, and so extra syntax is required to warn the caller. If escaping were the default, this would complicate calls that should be simple and reduce optimization opportunities.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift, closures are non-escaping by default. This means that the closure can't outlive the function it was passed into as a parameter. If you need to hold onto that closure after the function it was passed into returns, you'll need to mark the closure with the keyword @escaping